# cartesian product in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, cartesian-product, cross-join

I have two pandas dataframes:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df1 = DataFrame({'col1':[1,2],'col2':[3,4]})
df2 = DataFrame({'col3':[5,6]})
```

What is the best practice to get their cartesian product (of course without writing it explicitly like me)?

```
#df1, df2 cartesian product
df_cartesian = DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,1,2],'col2':[3,4,3,4],'col3':[5,5,6,6]})
```

Comment: From pandas 1.2 you will soon be able to use `left.merge(right, how="cross")` and it will work like magic. See this [github PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/37864).

Comment: It improves with readability of the question to show the dataframes in print/display format.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

In recent versions of Pandas (>= 1.2) this is built into `merge` so you can do:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df1 = DataFrame({'col1':[1,2],'col2':[3,4]})
df2 = DataFrame({'col3':[5,6]})    

df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

This is equivalent to the previous pandas < 1.2 answer but is easier to read.

---

For pandas < 1.2:

If you have a key that is repeated for each row, then you can produce a cartesian product using merge (like you would in SQL).

```
from pandas import DataFrame, merge
df1 = DataFrame({'key':[1,1], 'col1':[1,2],'col2':[3,4]})
df2 = DataFrame({'key':[1,1], 'col3':[5,6]})

merge(df1, df2,on='key')[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     1     3     6
2     2     4     5
3     2     4     6
```

See here for the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: So to do this properly one has to first find an unused column name, then add dummy columns with that name, merge, and finally drop the column on the result? Creating, as opposed to reading, data with pandas is just a pain

Comment: @Bananach woah! Relax my friend, it isn't that bad, they just hadn't gotten to it yet. Remember pandas is still a developing library and they only just released v1 recently. Anyway they are adding support for this in 1.2 inside df.merge(). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65017552/4909087) for more.

Comment: @cs95 thanks, I hadn't noticed this was coming in 1.2. In the future that should be the preferred approach

Comment: If all you want to do is merge two column, you can create df1 and df2 "anonymously" like so: `df[["purple"]].merge(df[["red"]], how="cross")`. Mind the double brackets `[["colname"]]` which makes them DataFrame and not Series.

Answer (score 110):

Use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` as an index in an otherwise empty dataframe, then reset its index, and you're done.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a, b], names = ["a", "b"])

pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()
```

out:

```
   a  b
0  1  a
1  1  b
2  1  c
3  2  a
4  2  b
5  2  c
6  3  a
7  3  b
8  3  c
```

Comment: I believe this is the most pandas-like way these days for pandas>=0.21

Comment: You have downvotes because you haven't shown how this is going to generalise for anything with more than 1 column.

Comment: This function (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58242079/1840471) generalizes it to an arbitrary number of lists using a dict of args. It's a bit different from the question here, which takes the Cartesian product of two DataFrames (i.e. it's not taking the product of `df1.col1` and `df.col2`).

Comment: In fact I don't think `from_product` can be used for this problem.

Comment: @MaxGhenis Don't think that is useful for this case, we aren't talking about cartesian products of multiple arrays, we are talking about 2 or more DataFrames (completely different story).

Answer (score 46):

Minimal code needed for this one. Create a common 'key' to cartesian merge the two:

```
df1['key'] = 0
df2['key'] = 0

df_cartesian = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

Comment: + `df_cartesian = df_cartesian.drop(columns=['key'])` to clean up at the end

Answer (score 38):

This won't win a code golf competition, and borrows from the previous answers - but clearly shows how the key is added, and how the join works. This creates 2 new data frames from lists, then adds the key to do the cartesian product on.

My use case was that I needed a list of all store IDs on for each week in my list. So, I created a list of all the weeks I wanted to have, then a list of all the store IDs I wanted to map them against.

The merge I chose left, but would be semantically the same as inner in this setup. You can see this [in the documentation on merging](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra), which states it does a Cartesian product if key combination appears more than once in both tables - which is what we set up.

```
days = pd.DataFrame({'date':list_of_days})
stores = pd.DataFrame({'store_id':list_of_stores})
stores['key'] = 0
days['key'] = 0
days_and_stores = days.merge(stores, how='left', on = 'key')
days_and_stores.drop('key',1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: A bit shorter version: `days_and_stores = pd.merge(days.assign(key=0), stores.assign(key=0), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)`

Comment: You mention crossJoin, but you are using a pandas dataframe, not a spark dataframe.

Comment: Dang. Wasn't thinking. I use spark + pandas together so often, that when I saw the update to spark I thought about this post. Thanks Bryce.

Answer (score 25):

With method chaining:

```
product = (
    df1.assign(key=1)
    .merge(df2.assign(key=1), on="key")
    .drop("key", axis=1)
)
```

Answer (score 19):

Presenting to you

#### pandas >= 1.2

## [`left.merge(right, how='cross')`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/37864)

```
import pandas as pd 

pd.__version__
# '1.2.0'

left = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
right = pd.DataFrame({'col3': [5, 6]}) 

left.merge(right, how='cross')

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     1     3     6
2     2     4     5
3     2     4     6
```

Indexes are ignored in the result.

Implementation wise, this uses the join on common key column method as described in the accepted answer. The upsides of using the API is that it saves you a lot of typing and handles some corner cases pretty well. I'd almost always recommend this syntax as my first preference for cartesian product in pandas unless you're looking for [something more performant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53699012/4909087).

Comment: Just checked https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v1.2.0, pandas 1.2 was released December 26, 2020. The cross merge works for me!

Answer (score 16):

As an alternative, one can rely on the cartesian product provided by itertools: `itertools.product`, which avoids creating a temporary key or modifying the index:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import itertools

def cartesian(df1, df2):
    rows = itertools.product(df1.iterrows(), df2.iterrows())

    df = pd.DataFrame(left.append(right) for (_, left), (_, right) in rows)
    return df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Quick test:

```
In [46]: a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3), columns=["a", "b", "c"])

In [47]: b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3), columns=["d", "e", "f"])    

In [48]: cartesian(a,b)
Out[48]:
           a         b         c         d         e         f
0   0.436480  0.068491  0.260292  0.991311  0.064167  0.715142
1   0.436480  0.068491  0.260292  0.101777  0.840464  0.760616
2   0.436480  0.068491  0.260292  0.655391  0.289537  0.391893
3   0.436480  0.068491  0.260292  0.383729  0.061811  0.773627
4   0.436480  0.068491  0.260292  0.575711  0.995151  0.804567
5   0.469578  0.052932  0.633394  0.991311  0.064167  0.715142
6   0.469578  0.052932  0.633394  0.101777  0.840464  0.760616
7   0.469578  0.052932  0.633394  0.655391  0.289537  0.391893
8   0.469578  0.052932  0.633394  0.383729  0.061811  0.773627
9   0.469578  0.052932  0.633394  0.575711  0.995151  0.804567
10  0.466813  0.224062  0.218994  0.991311  0.064167  0.715142
11  0.466813  0.224062  0.218994  0.101777  0.840464  0.760616
12  0.466813  0.224062  0.218994  0.655391  0.289537  0.391893
13  0.466813  0.224062  0.218994  0.383729  0.061811  0.773627
14  0.466813  0.224062  0.218994  0.575711  0.995151  0.804567
15  0.831365  0.273890  0.130410  0.991311  0.064167  0.715142
16  0.831365  0.273890  0.130410  0.101777  0.840464  0.760616
17  0.831365  0.273890  0.130410  0.655391  0.289537  0.391893
18  0.831365  0.273890  0.130410  0.383729  0.061811  0.773627
19  0.831365  0.273890  0.130410  0.575711  0.995151  0.804567
20  0.447640  0.848283  0.627224  0.991311  0.064167  0.715142
21  0.447640  0.848283  0.627224  0.101777  0.840464  0.760616
22  0.447640  0.848283  0.627224  0.655391  0.289537  0.391893
23  0.447640  0.848283  0.627224  0.383729  0.061811  0.773627
24  0.447640  0.848283  0.627224  0.575711  0.995151  0.804567
```

Comment: I tested this and it works, but it is much slower than above merge answers for large datasets.

Comment: @MrJ there's no other reason besides the usage of iterrows() here, it absolutely destroys any semblance of efficiency and takes minutes or hours for even a few thousand rows. Not worth it

Answer (score 2):

If you have no overlapping columns, don't want to add one, and the indices of the data frames can be discarded, this may be easier:

```
df1.index[:] = df2.index[:] = 0
df_cartesian = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
df_cartesian.index[:] = range(len(df_cartesian))
```

Comment: This looks promising - but I get the error on the first line:  `TypeError: '<class 'pandas.core.index.Int64Index'>' does not support mutable operations.`  I can get around this by adding `, index=[0,0]` to the dataframe definition though.

Comment: Or using `df1 = df1.set_index([[0]*len(df1)]))` (and similarly for `df2`).

Comment: Racing Tadpole's edits made this work for me - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a helper function to perform a simple Cartesian product with two data frames. The internal logic handles using an internal key, and avoids mangling any columns that happen to be named "key" from either side.

```
import pandas as pd

def cartesian(df1, df2):
    """Determine Cartesian product of two data frames."""
    key = 'key'
    while key in df1.columns or key in df2.columns:
        key = '_' + key
    key_d = {key: 0}
    return pd.merge(
        df1.assign(**key_d), df2.assign(**key_d), on=key).drop(key, axis=1)

# Two data frames, where the first happens to have a 'key' column
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'number':[1, 2], 'key':[3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'digit': [5, 6]})
cartesian(df1, df2)
```

shows:

```
   number  key  digit
0       1    3      5
1       1    3      6
2       2    4      5
3       2    4      6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start by taking the Cartesian product of `df1.col1` and `df2.col3`, then merge back to `df1` to get `col2`.

Here's a general Cartesian product function which takes a dictionary of lists:

```
def cartesian_product(d):
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(d.values(), names=d.keys())
    return pd.DataFrame(index=index).reset_index()
```

Apply as:

```
res = cartesian_product({'col1': df1.col1, 'col3': df2.col3})
pd.merge(res, df1, on='col1')
#  col1 col3 col2
# 0   1    5    3
# 1   1    6    3
# 2   2    5    4
# 3   2    6    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another workaround for the current version of Pandas (1.1.5): this one is particularly useful if you're starting off with a non-dataframe sequence. I haven't timed it. It does not require any artificial index manipulation, but does require that you repeat the second sequence. It relies on a special property of `explode`, namely that the right-hand index is repeated.

```py
df1 = DataFrame({'col1': [1,2], 'col2': [3,4]})

series2 = Series(
    [[5, 6]]*len(df1),
    name='col3',
    index=df1.index,
)

df_cartesian = df1.join(series2.explode())
```

This outputs

```
   col1  col2 col3
0     1     3    5
0     1     3    6
1     2     4    5
1     2     4    6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [expand_grid](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.expand_grid.html#janitor.expand_grid) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to replicate a cross join; it offers some speed performance for larger datasets (it uses `np.meshgrid` underneath):

```py
pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn
jn.expand_grid(others = {"df1":df1, "df2":df2})

   df1       df2
  col1 col2 col3
0    1    3    5
1    1    3    6
2    2    4    5
3    2    4    6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the cross product of two Series or DataFrames in such a way that the result is indexed correctly by the cross product of their two respective indices, that can be done like this:

```
def indexed_cross_product(df1, df2):
    assert df1.index.name is not None
    assert df2.index.name is not None
    assert df1.index.name != df2.index.name
    vals = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), how="cross")
    return vals.set_index([df1.index.name, df2.index.name], drop=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

I find using pandas MultiIndex to be the best tool for the job. If you have a list of lists `lists_list`, call `pd.MultiIndex.from_product(lists_list)` and iterate over the result (or use it in DataFrame index).