# Pandas 0.12 index immutable in python 3, not immutable in 2.7

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone know why the following code works in python 2.7, but not in python 3?

```
from pandas import *

df = {'one' : Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
'two' : Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = DataFrame(df)

df.index[:] = 0
```

In 2.7, this returns the following:

```
Index([0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
```

Whereas in python 3 I get:

```
Exception: <class 'pandas.core.index.Index'> object is immutable
```

I have checked the pandas version and it's 0.12.0 in both cases.

My understanding was that the index is immutable, so I am surprised that this code works in 2.7.

Thanks very much,

Robin

Comment: Can you print your pandas versions for 2.7 and 3? On pandas `'0.12.0-993-gda89834'` 2.7 it raises the exception.

Comment: Hello.  How do I get the more detailed version number?  I've tried pandas.__version__ and all it gives me is 0.12.0

Comment: That's the right way to get the version. Is that what you get for your python 2.7 and 3 pandas? I can't remember when the change was made, but I think it was after the .12 release (the current official release). All the extra stuff after the `0.12.0` is from git since I'm working off the current master.

Comment: Thanks.  It certainly looks like 0.12.0 on both 2.7 and 3.0.  So in future releases it will be immutable?  I was using the second answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas.  It looks like this way of creating a cartesian join will not work in future?