# Merging a dataframe with a Series

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe, series

A co-worker of mine is trying to combine a matrix and a Series and is trying to see if there is a native pandas way to do so instead of using a loop.

Example if I had a dataframe that consisted of

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

and a Series with values

```
13, 14, 15
```

Then the desired result would be

```
1, 2, 3, 13
1, 2, 3, 14
1, 2, 3, 15
4, 5, 6, 13
4, 5, 6, 14
4, 5, 6, 15
7, 8, 9, 13
7, 8, 9, 14
7, 8, 9, 15
```

Is there a pandas specific method of achieving this effect. I am not sure what specifically to search to find this and a few attempts of what was similar enough in my head failed.

Comment: possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas

Comment: Can we assume that the Series and the DataFrame use the same index values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with merge. If you want the full Cartesian product, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
df['key'] = 0
ser = pd.DataFrame({'data': [13,14,15], 'key': [0] * 3})

result = pd.merge(df, ser, on = 'key').drop('key', axis = 1)
```

I've checked result and it looks like what you want. More info if you search "Brief primer on merge methods (relational algebra)" in the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

Answer (score 0):

Someone had posted an answer that helped me get what I wanted, but then deleted it before i could come back to accept.

Basically what I needed to do was make the Series a dataframe and add a common column to both assuming these are called a and b i just

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: a = pd.DataFrame({1:[1,4,7],2:[2,5,8],3:[3,6,9]})

In [3]: a
Out[3]:
   1  2  3
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9


In [5]: b = pd.DataFrame({4:[13,14,15]})

In [6]: b
Out[6]:
    4
0  13
1  14
2  15

In [7]: a["key"] = 1

In [8]: b["key"] = 1

In [9]: c = a.merge(b, on="key")

In [10]: c
Out[10]:
   1  2  3  key   4
0  1  2  3    1  13
1  1  2  3    1  14
2  1  2  3    1  15
3  4  5  6    1  13
4  4  5  6    1  14
5  4  5  6    1  15
6  7  8  9    1  13
7  7  8  9    1  14
8  7  8  9    1  15

In [11]: del c["key"]

In [12]: c
Out[12]:
   1  2  3   4
0  1  2  3  13
1  1  2  3  14
2  1  2  3  15
3  4  5  6  13
4  4  5  6  14
5  4  5  6  15
6  7  8  9  13
7  7  8  9  14
8  7  8  9  15

In [13]:
```