# pandas two dataframe cross join

Tags: python, pandas

I can't find anything about cross join include the  merge/join or some other.
I need deal with two dataframe using {my function} as  myfunc .
the equivalent of :

```
{
    for itemA in df1.iterrows():
           for itemB in df2.iterrows():
                       t["A"] = myfunc(itemA[1]["A"],itemB[1]["A"])
 }
```

the equivalent of :

```
{
 select myfunc(df1.A,df2.A),df1.A,df2.A from df1,df2;
}
```

but I need more efficient solution:
if used apply i will  be how to implement them  thx;^^

Comment: did you get this worked out?  Comment on my answer if you have questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the cross product, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas).

Essentially, you have to do a normal merge but give every row the same key to join on, so that every row is joined to each other across the frames.

You can then add a column to the new frame by applying your function:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=key)
new_df.new_col = new_df.apply(lambda row: myfunc(row['A_x'], row['A_y']), axis=1)
```

`axis=1` forces `.apply` to work across the rows. 'A_x' and 'A_y' will be the default column names in the resulting frame if the merged frames share a column like in your example above.

Answer (score 65):

Create a common 'key' to cross join the two:

```
df1['key'] = 0
df2['key'] = 0

df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='outer')
```

Comment: As scrappy as this method is, it is very conceptually easy to understand! Thanks

Comment: you also need on='key' in the merge statement

Comment: I don't think the `how` parameter has any impact on the result. You could leave it out and go with the default (which is `inner`)

Comment: @alejandro OP specifically requests cross join which is the same as an outer, NOT an inner.

Comment: @A.Kot I see your point, but talking strictly about your code, using the `how` parameter does not affect because you are joining on a constant key, which will always match, so `inner` does not eliminate any of the rows