# Iterate through a pandas dataframe, check each column value with an if statement and pass the column values to the prefered column of an empty df

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas a dataframe like this

```
    Event_Id       Investigation_Type Accident_Number   Event_Date      
0   20180922X71035  ACCIDENT          DCA18CA289        09/10/2018  
1   20180507X00658  ACCIDENT          DCA18CA169        05/07/2018  
4   20171212X50255  ACCIDENT          DCA18CA043B       12/03/2017
```

and I try to iterate through it like this...

```
n1col = 0
n2col = 1

for i in df.index:
    Node1=df.Event_Id
    for j in df.index:
        Node2=df.Event_Id
        if (Node1 != Node2):
            new_df.loc[j,n1col] = Node1
            new_df.loc[j,n2col] = Node2
```

I don't know if my approach is right (as I see it's not) I want some help so I can get a result like the one below...

I am new to that kind of stuff so I need your help.

```
    Node_1          Node_2 
0   20180922X71035  20180507X00658
1   20180922X71035  20171212X50255
2   20180507X00658  20180922X71035
3   20180507X00658  20171212X50255
4   20171212X50255  20180922X71035
6   20171212X50255  20180507X00658
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one line with

```
from itertools import combinations

pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(df.index.tolist(), 2)), columns=['Node1', 'Node2'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day!!

Comment: You're very welcome. If you're new to Pandas you'll discover that you can do an enormous amount without using loops.

Comment: In your original post, aren't you asking for a cartesian product and excluding the records where they're equal? I didn't think you were looking for combination

Comment: @Orenshi Is there any difference if it is a cartesian product or a combination?  My goal is to create a network with these ids and visualize it(if this helps).

Answer (score 2):

I know you've already accepted an answer. But in case you are not looking for a combination and instead want the cartesian product and then filter it down such that the 2 columns are not equal...

```
>>> df
         Event_Id Accident_Number  Event_Date Investigation_Type
0  20180922X71035      DCA18CA289  09/10/2018           ACCIDENT
1  20180507X00658      DCA18CA169  05/07/2018           ACCIDENT
2  20171212X50255     DCA18CA043B  12/03/2017           ACCIDENT
```

Get the Cartesian Product [Answer from this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161978/pandas-two-dataframe-cross-join)

```
>>> df['key'] = 0
>>> df
         Event_Id Accident_Number  Event_Date Investigation_Type  key
0  20180922X71035      DCA18CA289  09/10/2018           ACCIDENT    0
1  20180507X00658      DCA18CA169  05/07/2018           ACCIDENT    0
2  20171212X50255     DCA18CA043B  12/03/2017           ACCIDENT    0
>>> df2 = df.merge(df, on='key').filter(items=['Event_Id_x', 'Event_Id_y'])
>>> df2
       Event_Id_x      Event_Id_y
0  20180922X71035  20180922X71035
1  20180922X71035  20180507X00658
2  20180922X71035  20171212X50255
3  20180507X00658  20180922X71035
4  20180507X00658  20180507X00658
5  20180507X00658  20171212X50255
6  20171212X50255  20180922X71035
7  20171212X50255  20180507X00658
8  20171212X50255  20171212X50255
```

Use [.loc/boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter down your DataFrame

```
>>> df2.loc[df2['Event_Id_x'] != df2['Event_Id_y']]
       Event_Id_x      Event_Id_y
1  20180922X71035  20180507X00658
2  20180922X71035  20171212X50255
3  20180507X00658  20180922X71035
5  20180507X00658  20171212X50255
6  20171212X50255  20180922X71035
7  20171212X50255  20180507X00658
```

Similar to Josh's answer using itertools. But this time using product instead of combination:

```
>>> df = df.set_index('Event_Id')
>>> df3 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df.index.tolist(), df.index.tolist())), columns=['Node1', 'Node2'])
>>> df3.loc[df3['Node1'] != df3['Node2']]
            Node1           Node2
1  20180922X71035  20180507X00658
2  20180922X71035  20171212X50255
3  20180507X00658  20180922X71035
5  20180507X00658  20171212X50255
6  20171212X50255  20180922X71035
7  20171212X50255  20180507X00658
```

Comment: @Orenshi, this great show, however second solution doesn't yield the shown results.

Comment: Good point. I forgot to add setting the index to the second solution. Or alternatively instead of df.index.tolist() you can use df.Event_Id.tolist()

Comment: @Orenshi I will keep that solution in my mind for future problems.