# Combine two unequal dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=["d","e"],data=[(3,1),(2,4),(8,4),(5,1)])
```

looking like this:

```
    d   e
0   3   1
1   2   4
2   8   4
3   5   1
```

and another `df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b","c"],data=[(3,4,5)])` that looks like that:

```
    a   b   c
0   3   4   5
```

I want to add the one row dataframe to the bigger one repeating the same values across rows: Expected result is like this:

```
    d   e   a   b   c
0   3   1   3   4   5
1   2   4   3   4   5
2   8   4   3   4   5
3   5   1   3   4   5
```

Comment: Another dupe: [datarames cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34161978/12416453)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["d","e"],data=[(3,1),(2,4),(8,4),(5,1)])                               
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b","c"],data=[(3,4,5)]

# Create a common key
df1['key'] = 0
df2['key'] = 0

result = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')

# Remove the key if you don't need it
del result['key']
```

`result`:

```
   d  e  a  b  c
0  3  1  3  4  5
1  2  4  3  4  5
2  8  4  3  4  5
3  5  1  3  4  5
```