# count pair id matches via proxy id - mongodb etc.?

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, dataframe, neo4j

suppose I have a very big data.frame/collection with the field id and an proxy id.

```
   1 a
   2 a
   1 b
   3 b
   1 c
   3 c
   4 d
```

Now I'd like to count/get the matches which id has with another id.

```
   1 2 1 #id1 id2 count
   1 3 2
```

Ok with some python itertools.combinations and lookups this works. But feels cumbersome. Is there an more approriate simple fast approach/technology?

My approach later appended:

- I filtered the ids which are appear > x , beacuse I have millions.

  `def matchings(id):
      #mapping is the mongodb collection
      match = mapping.find({'id':id})
      valid_proxies = [doc['proxy']  for doc in match]
      other_ids = [doc['id'] for doc in mapping.find({'proxy': {'$in':valid_proxies}})]
      c = Counter([(id, id2) for id2 in other_ids if id2 !=id])
      #possible filter
      #c_filtered {k:v for k, v in c.items() if v > 3 }
      #some stats
      #s1 = [id,len(proxies),len(other_ids)]
      s2 = [[k[0],k[1],v] for k,v in c.items()]
      return s2`

  `res = [matchings(id) for id in list(df_id_filtered['id'])]
   df_final_matching_counts = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.chain(*res)))`

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain your expected outcome in more detail?!

Comment: Sure. id 1 and 2 have in my example only 1 time the same "proxy" which is a. But id 1 and 3 have two times the same "proxy" which is b and c. id 4 matches with no one , because it is the only one with "proxy" d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was my approach

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 3, 6: 4}, 'proxy': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'b', 4: 'c', 5: 'c', 6: 'd'}})
print df
```

group by and *aggregate* into **sets**

```
df_g = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: set(x['proxy'])).to_frame()
df_g.columns = ['proxy']
```

a trick to make cartesian product [cartesian product in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas)

```
df_g['X'] = 'X'
merged = pd.merge(df_g.reset_index(),df_g.reset_index(), on = ['X'])
```

which gives:

```
    id_x    proxy_x  X  id_y    proxy_y
0      1  {a, c, b}  X     1  {a, c, b}
1      1  {a, c, b}  X     2        {a}
2      1  {a, c, b}  X     3     {c, b}
3      1  {a, c, b}  X     4        {d}
4      2        {a}  X     1  {a, c, b}
5      2        {a}  X     2        {a}
6      2        {a}  X     3     {c, b}
7      2        {a}  X     4        {d}
8      3     {c, b}  X     1  {a, c, b}
9      3     {c, b}  X     2        {a}
10     3     {c, b}  X     3     {c, b}
11     3     {c, b}  X     4        {d}
12     4        {d}  X     1  {a, c, b}
13     4        {d}  X     2        {a}
14     4        {d}  X     3     {c, b}
15     4        {d}  X     4        {d}
```

some tidy up

```
# we dont care about (1,1) (2,2), (3,3) etc.
merged_filtered =  merged[merged['id_x'] != merged['id_y'] ].copy(deep=True)

# use intersection on the sets, sorted list (or set) for the keys & len()
merged_filtered['intersect']  = merged_filtered.apply(lambda row: len(row['proxy_x'].intersection(row['proxy_y'])), axis=1)

# for us (1,2) = (2,1) etc. sorting or set, then drop duplicates will address that.
merged_filtered['keys'] = merged_filtered.apply(lambda row: sorted([row['id_x'],row['id_y']]),axis=1)
merged_filtered = merged_filtered[['keys','intersect']]
```

there are other ways to split the column of list objects into two columns

```
merged_filtered['key1'] = merged_filtered['keys'].map(lambda x: x[0])
merged_filtered['key2'] = merged_filtered['keys'].map(lambda x: x[1])
merged_filtered.drop('keys', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

now drop the duplicates

```
merged_filtered = merged_filtered.drop_duplicates().set_index(['key1','key2'])
print merged_filtered

           intersect
key1 key2           
1    2             1
     3             2
     4             0
2    3             0
     4             0
3    4             0
```

and if you want to drop the zeros:

```
print merged_filtered[merged_filtered['intersect'] !=0]

           intersect
key1 key2           
1    2             1
     3             2
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the input data looks like this:

```
[{id: 1, p: 'a'}, {id: 2, p: 'a'}, {id: 1, p: 'b'}, {id: 3, p: 'b'}, {id: 1, p: 'c'}, {id: 3, p: 'c'}, {id: 4, p: 'd'}]
```

Here is a Cypher query (tested with neo4j 3.1, which is in Beta) that will return the expected counts. *This example specifies the input `data` using a `WITH`, but in practice you would get the data in some other way (e.g., through a `MATCH` or via a parameter).*

```
WITH [{id: 1, p: 'a'}, {id: 2, p: 'a'}, {id: 1, p: 'b'}, {id: 3, p: 'b'}, {id: 1, p: 'c'}, {id: 3, p: 'c'}, {id: 4, p: 'd'}] AS data
UNWIND data AS d
WITH d.id AS id, COLLECT(d.p) AS ps
WITH COLLECT({id: id, ps: ps}) AS c
WITH
  REDUCE(s=[], i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(c)-2) |
    s + {id1: c[i].id, x:
      REDUCE(t=[], j IN RANGE(i+1, SIZE(c)-1) |
        t + {id2: c[j].id, ct:
          REDUCE(u=0, k IN RANGE(0, SIZE(c[i].ps)-1) |
            CASE WHEN (c[i].ps)[k] IN c[j].ps THEN u + 1 ELSE u END
          )
        }
      )
    }
  ) AS temp
UNWIND temp AS temp_row
UNWIND temp_row.x AS x
WITH temp_row.id1 AS id1, x.id2 AS id2, x.ct AS ct
WHERE ct > 0
RETURN id1, id2, ct;
```

The query steps through the data and counts the number of times each id pair shares the same proxy (`p`) value. It then returns each pair and its count, as long as the count exceeds 0.

The result of the above query is:

```
╒═══╤═══╤═══╕
│id1│id2│ct │
╞═══╪═══╪═══╡
│2  │1  │1  │
├───┼───┼───┤
│1  │3  │2  │
└───┴───┴───┘
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll look intot it. Porblem with the cartesian product is, that it blows up my machine. So scripted a more iterative solution with mongodb & python ( see above)