# pandas-two columns' values are list, need to generate a new df to show all combination of values between them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have:

```
df1=
col1      col2     col3
[a,b]    [c,d]     0.5
[e,f]    [g,h]     0.7
```

want to return a new df2 based on df1:

```
df2=
col1  col2  col3
 a     c    0.5
 a     d    0.5
 b     c    0.5
 b     d    0.5
 e     g    0.7
 e     h    0.7
 f     g    0.7
 f     h    0.7
```

Basically, need to show all combination between the lists in df1's col1 and col2, the length of lists may be larger than 2.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I break down the steps

```
import itertools
df['Min']=list(zip(df.col1,df.col2))
df['New']=df.Min.apply(lambda x : list(itertools.product(x[0],x[1])))
df1=df.set_index('col3')['New']
df1.apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series).reset_index().\
       drop('level_1',1).rename(columns={0:'col1',1:'col2'})

Out[588]: 
   col3 col1 col2
0   0.5    a    c
1   0.5    a    d
2   0.5    b    c
3   0.5    b    d
4   0.7    e    g
5   0.7    e    h
6   0.7    f    g
7   0.7    f    h
```

Answer (score 1):

A kind of hacky way is just to write out the comprehension:

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame([{"col1": c1, "col2": c2, "col3": row["col3"]} 
                       for _, row in df.iterrows()
                       for c1 in row["col1"] for c2 in row["col2"]])
Out[11]:
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    c   0.5
1    a    d   0.5
2    b    c   0.5
3    b    d   0.5
4    e    g   0.7
5    e    h   0.7
6    f    g   0.7
7    f    h   0.7
```