# Python PANDAS: Merge Equivalent of "<=" SQL Join

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

In pandas, is there an equivalent merge or merge_asof operation that can accomplish the SQL equivalent of an:

```
INNER JOIN number_table as n on n.N <= t.some_integer_field 

where n is a number/tally table dataframe with a single column of integers(1 to 1000)
and t is a table with some integer field you would like to "deaggregate"
```

Any tips would be most appreciated!

Comment: I have read the docs but how to accommodate the "<=" on the join key criteria is my question.

Comment: How would this mapping work? It is usually done in SQL with at least one other columns in the join

Comment: you should just look at filtering your data after you merge. I don't think you can currently use `dataframe.merge()` method with conditionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, the `INNER JOIN` without equality is equivalent to `CROSS JOIN` and `ON` can be replaced with `WHERE`. Technically, even with equality! So your need of:

```sql
INNER JOIN number_table as n ON n.N <= t.some_integer_field
```

Can be replaced as:

```sql
CROSS JOIN number_table as n WHERE n.N <= t.some_integer_field
```

And because cross joins are [cartesian products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), run the same [process in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13269890/1422451) where you assign a column in both dataframes of same value and `merge` on it which returns all possible combinations of rows from both sets since *key* will align.

```
df_number['key'] = 1  # OR df_number.assign(key=1)
df_table['key'] = 1

# CROSS JOIN WITH CONDITIONAL FILTER
pd.merge(df_table, df_number, on='key').query('N < some_integer_field')
```

Now performance of CJs is another question!

Comment: Thanks for explaining the intersection of these concepts!  This approach turns out to have similar performance to my existing pandas program, but it is good to see how other options compare.

Comment: Great glad to help. Yes, CJs are not the best performance especially with large datasets.