# Pandas: how to join two dataframes combinatorially

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I would like to combine combinatorial-wise (i.e. combinatorially join each row from one df to each row of another df).  I can do this by merging on 'key's but my solution is clearly cumbersome.  I'm looking for a more straightforward, even pythonesque way of handling this operation.  Any suggestions?

MWE:

```
fred = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1., 4.],'B':[2., 5.], 'C':[3., 6.]})
print(fred)
    A    B    C
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  5.0  6.0

jim = pd.DataFrame({'one':['a', 'c'],'two':['b', 'd']})
print(jim)
   one two
0   a   b
1   c   d


fred['key'] = [1,2]
jim1 = jim.copy()
jim1['key'] = 1
jim2 = jim.copy()
jim2['key'] = 2
jim3 = jim1.append(jim2)

jack = pd.merge(fred, jim3, on='key').drop(['key'], axis=1)
print(jack)
    A    B    C   one two
0  1.0  2.0  3.0   a   b
1  1.0  2.0  3.0   c   d
2  4.0  5.0  6.0   a   b
3  4.0  5.0  6.0   c   d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join every row of `fred` with every row of `jim` by merging on a `key` column which is equal to the same value (say, 1) for every row:

```
In [16]: pd.merge(fred.assign(key=1), jim.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
Out[16]: 
     A    B    C one two
0  1.0  2.0  3.0   a   b
1  1.0  2.0  3.0   c   d
2  4.0  5.0  6.0   a   b
3  4.0  5.0  6.0   c   d
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the cartesian product of the two dataframes, like a cross join?

It is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas).