# pandas advanced conditional groupby

Tags: python, pandas

For each day of the month (1-31), I want to compute the number of trips occurring within any 60 minute period on that day,so like the first entry is 0:00, I want to get the number of trips from 0:00 to 1:00, the second entry is 0:01,I want to get the number of trips from 0:01 to 1:01.

And it must be within the same day, so from 23:00, you do not need to count the number of trips

How to do groupby on this ?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't sound like a group-by operation to me since you end up with the same number of rows you began with (no aggregation). Seems more like a function you would apply on your frame's rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a few steps:

- group by pickup time and count how many trips occur in each minute (I'm assuming you're doing this based on pickup time), call this dataframe `by_minute`
- cross join `by_minute` with itself (so you have the cartesian product) and filter to the rows where the two pickup times satisfy your condition
- group by (the "left hand") pickup time and sum the counts of the "right hand" trips

I believe you'll have to add a dummy column to `by_minute` to facilitate the join. Something like:

```
by_minute['key'] = 1
joined = by_minute.merge(by_minute, on='key')
```

There are some other options mentioned [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas). `merge` has a `suffixes` argument (by default it's `('_x', '_y')` that will distinguish the column names.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment, as far as I can tell, you're not looking for a groupby, but rather some operation on each row.
I came up with the following solution using apply:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df["pickup_datetime"])    # make sure the pickup column is datetime
r = s.apply(lambda x: np.sum(s.between(x, x + pd.Timedelta("1hr")) & (s.dt.dayofyear == x.dayofyear)))
```

Lets break it down:
This will go over each row (`apply`) and create a Boolean mask based on two conditions:

- All the pickup times that fall within an hour from the current pickup time.
- All the pickup times that are within the same date (day of the year) as the current pickup time.

We then combine them with an AND operation (&).
This have created a boolean array the size of your Series with `True` wherever both conditions are met.
Finally, we sum (`np` for Numpy) this boolean array which is equivalent to counting the number of entries that met the condition above.