# Maintain Identifiers While Finding Distance Between Lat and Long

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, geopy

I have two sets of lats and longs that I wish to join with a Cartesian join and find the distance between each pair. There **can** be duplicates in `number` or `other_number` (i.e. two locations/addresses per identifier).

```
d = {'number': ['100', '101'], 'lat': ['40.6892', '41.8902'], 'long': ['74.0445','12.4922']}
d2 = {'other_number': ['200', '201'], 'lat': ['37.8199', '43.8791'], 'long': ['122.4783','103.4591']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

I am currently turning the lat/long fields into lists of tuples...

```
tuple_list_1 = list(zip(data.lat.astype(float), data.long.astype(float)))
tuple_list_2 = list(zip(data2.lat.astype(float), data2.long.astype(float)))
```

...and then performing the Cartesian join with a generator.

```
gen = ([x, y] for x in tuple_list_1 for y in tuple_list_2)
```

Finally, I am finding the distance with a simple loop:

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic

for u, v in gen:
    dist = geodesic(u, v).miles
    print(dist)
```

Ultimately, I would like the distance tied back to the original information (i.e. `number` and `other_number`). This is my desired result:

```
    d3 = {'number': ['100', '100','100','100'], 
     'address': ['Statue of Liberty', 'Statue of Liberty', 'Colosseum', 'Colosseum'],
     'other_number': ['200', '200', '201', '201'],
     'other_address': ['Golden Gate Bridge','Mount Rushmore','Golden Gate Bridge','Mount Rushmore'],
     'distance':[2572.262967759492,1515.3455804766047,5400.249562015358,4365.4386483486205]
    }
data3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d3)
```

How do I retrieve the distance efficiently (I'm thinking looping through the generator may not be that efficient), and tie the results back to the identifying fields in a final DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'number': ['100', '101'], 'lat': ['40.6892', '41.8902'], 'long': ['74.0445','12.4922']}
d2 = {'other_number': ['200', '201'], 'lat': ['37.8199', '43.8791'], 'long': ['122.4783','103.4591']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

# Perform cartesian product
data['key'] = 0
data2['key'] = 0
df = pd.merge(data, data2, on='key', how='outer')
df = df.drop('key', axis=1)

# Calculate distance
from geopy.distance import geodesic
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda row: geodesic((row['lat_x'], row['long_x']), (row['lat_y'], row['long_y'])).miles, axis=1)
```

`df` would look like this:

```
  number    lat_x   long_x other_number    lat_y    long_y     distance
0    100  40.6892  74.0445          200  37.8199  122.4783  2572.262968
1    100  40.6892  74.0445          201  43.8791  103.4591  1515.345580
2    101  41.8902  12.4922          200  37.8199  122.4783  5400.249562
3    101  41.8902  12.4922          201  43.8791  103.4591  4365.438648
```

There're other ways of performing cartesian product in pandas if you don't like this one via a new `key` column, see [cartesian product in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13269890).