# How to assign a value to a column for every row of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I've been trying to assign a value for every row of a dataframe and I haven't been able to do so (I'm new in pandas), so if anyone could help, I'd be super grateful!

I've got two dataframes. In the input dataframe, I have brands:

```
brand_raw.head()

brand_name
0   Nike
1   Lacoste
2   Adidas
```

And then, on the output dataset, I have objects:

```
object_raw.head()

category_id object_name
0   24  T-shirt
1   45  Shorts
2   32  Dress
```

and what I would need to have is a dataframe with all the objects combined with all the brands:

```
to_raw.head()

category_id object_name brand_name
0   24  T-shirt     Nike
1   45  Shorts      Nike
2   32  Dress       Nike
3   24  T-shirt     Lacoste
4   45  Shorts      Lacoste
5   32  Dress       Lacoste
6   24  T-shirt     Adidas
7   45  Shorts      Adidas
8   32  Dress       Adidas
```

I've been trying to do it with the apply function, iterating over the rows, but I end up overwriting the values so I write the last brand:

```
0   24  T-shirt     Nike
1   45  Shorts      Nike
2   32  Dress       Nike
```

This is my code:

```
def insert_value_in_every_row(input_df, output_df, column_name):
    for row in input_df.values:
        row = row[0].rstrip()

        output_df[column_name] = output_df[column_name].apply(lambda x: row) 
    return output_df


insert_value_in_every_row(brand_raw, to_raw, 'brand_name')
```

Could someone give me a hint on how to deal with this, please? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can try and take a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas

Comment: I'll take a look at it! thanks @BornTbeWasted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of both dataframes. One way around this in pandas is to create a common and unique *key* for both dataframes and perform a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (any, as there is a complete overlap):

```
df.assign(key=0).merge(object_raw.assign(key=0), on='key').drop(['key'], axis=1)

   brand_name  category_id object_name
0       Nike           24     T-shirt
1       Nike           45      Shorts
2       Nike           32       Dress
3    Lacoste           24     T-shirt
4    Lacoste           45      Shorts
5    Lacoste           32       Dress
6     Adidas           24     T-shirt
7     Adidas           45      Shorts
8     Adidas           32       Dress
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which gives *Cartesian product of input iterables.*

```
import itertools
df=(pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(brand_name.brand_name,object_raw.object_name))
             ,columns=['brand_name','object_name']))
df['category_id']=df['object_name'].map(object_raw.set_index('object_name')['category_id'])
print(df)
```

---

```
  brand_name object_name  category_id
0       Nike     T-shirt           24
1       Nike      Shorts           45
2       Nike       Dress           32
3    Lacoste     T-shirt           24
4    Lacoste      Shorts           45
5    Lacoste       Dress           32
6     Adidas     T-shirt           24
7     Adidas      Shorts           45
8     Adidas       Dress           32
```

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a cartesian product.  In pandas its a bit tricky, but you could do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

objects = pd.DataFrame(["T-shirt","Shorts","Dress"],columns = ['object'])
brands =  pd.DataFrame(["Nike","Lacoste","Adidas"],columns = ['brand'])

objects["key"] = 1
brands ["key"] = 1

objects.merge(brands,on='key').drop('key',axis=1)
```