# I want to explode an numpy array and apply the values to a single column multiple times

Tags: python, pandas

I want to explode the numpy.ndarray and apply the each values of the array to the first element of the dataframe. Here is the input

```
Here is my dataframe

Id       Dept

100    Healthcare


Here is my numpy.ndarray

array(['2007-01-03', '2007-01-10', '2007-01-17', '2007-01-24'], dtype='datetime64[D]')


The Output looks like    
Id       Dept            Date

100    Healthcare        2007-01-03
100    Healthcare        2007-01-10
100    Healthcare        2007-01-17
100    Healthcare        2007-01-24

​
```

I need help to implement this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and using the length of your array:

```
x = np.array(['2007-01-03', '2007-01-10', '2007-01-17', '2007-01-24'], dtype='datetime64[D]')

df = pd.concat([df]*len(x))
df['Date'] = x

print(df)
    Id        Dept       Date
0  100  Healthcare 2007-01-03
0  100  Healthcare 2007-01-10
0  100  Healthcare 2007-01-17
0  100  Healthcare 2007-01-24
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an "all-to-all" matching you can do a [cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13269890/1782792):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[100, 'Healthcare']], columns=['Id', 'Dept'])
date = np.array(['2007-01-03', '2007-01-10', '2007-01-17', '2007-01-24'],
                dtype='datetime64[D]')

df['_tmp'] = 0
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date})
df2['_tmp'] = 0
result = pd.merge(df, df2, on='_tmp').drop('_tmp', axis=1)
print(result)
#     Id        Dept       Date
# 0  100  Healthcare 2007-01-03
# 1  100  Healthcare 2007-01-10
# 2  100  Healthcare 2007-01-17
# 3  100  Healthcare 2007-01-24
```

This makes it more easily extendable to the case where you have more than one row in the first data frame, if that is relevant for you:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[100, 'Healthcare'], [200, 'Security']], columns=['Id', 'Dept'])
date = np.array(['2007-01-03', '2007-01-10', '2007-01-17', '2007-01-24'],
                dtype='datetime64[D]')

df['_tmp'] = 0
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date})
df2['_tmp'] = 0
result = pd.merge(df, df2, on='_tmp').drop('_tmp', axis=1)
print(result)
#     Id        Dept       Date
# 0  100  Healthcare 2007-01-03
# 1  100  Healthcare 2007-01-10
# 2  100  Healthcare 2007-01-17
# 3  100  Healthcare 2007-01-24
# 4  200    Security 2007-01-03
# 5  200    Security 2007-01-10
# 6  200    Security 2007-01-17
# 7  200    Security 2007-01-24
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in column order, you can use the fact that assigning a single value to a new column, its length adapts to the dataframe's length:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(['2007-01-03', '2007-01-10', '2007-01-17', '2007-01-24'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': arr})
df['Id'] = 100
df['Dept'] = 'Healthcare'

#          Date   Id        Dept
# 0  2007-01-03  100  Healthcare                              
# 1  2007-01-10  100  Healthcare                            
# 2  2007-01-17  100  Healthcare                             
# 3  2007-01-24  100  Healthcare
```