# combine a Data frame to specific Row Value (for n Rows, append a Data frame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frame, i need to combine like below

This is my Data frame 1

[image]

This is my Data frame 2

[image]

i want my output as below :

[image]

Comment: Potentially it might be like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas.

Comment: Yes. Cartesian product concept worked for me after converting Column into a list. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df1['symbol'], df2['symbol']], 
    names=['col1', 'col2'])

pd.DataFrame(index=index).reset_index()
```

```
    col1    col2
0   L160    K-AL
1   L160    K-PL
2   L170    K-AL
3   L170    K-PL
4   L180    K-AL
5   L180    K-PL
```

Edit:

even better now thanks to [@Andy L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10189214/andy-l):

```py
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['symbol'], df2['symbol']], names=['col1', 'col2']) \
    .to_frame(index=False)
```

Comment: you may use `to_frame` to chain it `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['symbol'], df2['symbol']], names=['col1', 'col2']).to_frame(index=False)`

Comment: @AndyL. Thanks for this solution

Answer (score 3):

`Assign` an artificial key column and `merge` on it to get all the matches:

```
df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key', suffixes=['_1', '_2']).drop('key', axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
  symbol_1 symbol_2
0     L160     K-AL
1     L160     K-PL
2     L170     K-AL
3     L170     K-PL
4     L180     K-AL
5     L180     K-PL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 = DataFrame({'key':[1,1,1],'symbol':['L160','L170','L180']})
df2 = DataFrame({'key':[1,1],'symbol':['K-PL','K-AL']})
merge(df1, df2,on='key')[['col1', 'col2']]
```

Basically its a cartesian product. [LINK](https://db.grussell.org/section010.html)

OUTPUT

```
  key symbol_x symbol_y
0    1     L160     K-PL
1    1     L160     K-AL
2    1     L170     K-PL
3    1     L170     K-AL
4    1     L180     K-PL
5    1     L180     K-AL
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Numpy can also work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(['L160', 'L170', 'L180'],columns=['symbol'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['K-AL', 'K-PL'],columns=['symbol'])

np.transpose([np.tile(df1['symbol'], len(df2['symbol'])), np.repeat(df2['symbol'], len(df1['symbol']))])
```

Or directly in a Pandas dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([np.tile(df1['symbol'], len(df2['symbol'])), np.repeat(df2['symbol'], len(df1['symbol']))]))
```