# Cartesian product of arbitrary lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given an arbitrary number of lists, I'd like to produce a pandas `DataFrame` as the Cartesian product. For example, given:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['val1', 'val2']
c = [100, 101]
```

I'd like to end up with a `DataFrame` with columns `a`, `b`, and `c`, and all 3x2x2=12 combinations.

Unlike [cartesian product in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13269890/1840471), I'm looking for the ability to provide more than two inputs, and I am not looking to pass `DataFrame`s, which would involve keeping values within the same `DataFrame` together rather than taking combinations of it. Answers to this question will likely not overlap with answers to that one.

Unlike [Cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11144513/1840471), I'm seeking a pandas `DataFrame` result, with named columns, rather than a two-dimensional numpy array.

Comment: Appreciate your attempt to expand on the other answer and create a more generalized way to do this ;} . However, it is still too similar to the original answer, and therefore I'm marking as a dupe !

Comment: There's also an extensive discussion of how to make a fast cartesian product in the link I added. Granted that deals with arrays, but one could simply do `pd.DataFrame(cartesian_product(*[np.array(x) for x in [a,b,c]]))`

Comment: @rafaelc This isn't just a more generalized version of the "cartesian product in pandas" question. That question asks for a Cartesian product between two DataFrames, keeping values within the same DataFrame together rather than taking combinations of it. The answer I provided will not address that question. The numpy question is more similar, but the time test doesn't include the `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` approach I provided.

Comment: Also the numpy question doesn't involve column names in the result, which would require a second additional step.

Answer (score 9):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46744050/1840471) to a related question (Cartesian product of two `DataFrame`s), this function takes a dictionary of lists and returns the Cartesian product:

```
def cartesian_product(d):
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(d.values(), names=d.keys())
    return pd.DataFrame(index=index).reset_index()
```

Example:

```
cartesian_product({'a': [1, 2, 3],
                   'b': ['val1', 'val2'],
                   'c': [100, 101]})
    a      b      c
0   1   val1    100
1   1   val1    101
2   1   val2    100
3   1   val2    101
4   2   val1    100
5   2   val1    101
6   2   val2    100
7   2   val2    101
8   3   val1    100
9   3   val1    101
10  3   val2    100
11  3   val2    101
```

I've added this to my [`microdf` package](https://github.com/PSLmodels/microdf).