# create a NxN matrix from one column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have dataframe with each row having a list value.

```
id     list_of_value
0      ['a','b','c']
1      ['d','b','c']
2      ['a','b','c']
3      ['a','b','c']
```

i have to do a calculate a score with one row and against all the other rows

For eg:

```
Step 1: Take value of id 0: ['a','b','c'],
Step 2: find the intersection between id 0 and id 1 , 
        resultant = ['b','c']
Step 3: Score Calculation => resultant.size / id.size
```

**repeat step 2,3 between id 0 and id 1,2,3, similarly for all the ids.**

and create a N x N dataframe; such as this:

```
-  0  1    2  3
0  1  0.6  1  1
1  1  1    1  1 
2  1  1    1  1
3  1  1    1  1
```

Right now my code has just one for loop:

```
def scoreCalc(x,queryTData):
    #mathematical calculation
    commonTData = np.intersect1d(np.array(x),queryTData)
    return commonTData.size/queryTData.size

ids = list(df['feed_id'])
dfSim = pd.DataFrame()

for indexQFID in range(len(ids)):
    queryTData = np.array(df.loc[df['id'] == ids[indexQFID]]['list_of_value'].values.tolist())

    dfSim[segmentDfFeedIds[indexQFID]] = segmentDf['list_of_value'].apply(scoreCalc,args=(queryTData,))
```

Is there a better way to do this? can i just write one apply function instead doing a for-loop iteration.
 can i make it faster?

Comment: it is not 6, it is 0.6, resultant.size = 2, id.size = 3

Comment: How long is your data? and totally how many values occur in `list_of_value`?

Comment: maximum of 20 values in each list_of_value

Comment: Not in each `list_of_value`. I mean in total, across all the rows.

Comment: 12 thousand rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you data is not too big, you can use `get_dummies` to encode the values and do a matrix multiplication:

```
s = pd.get_dummies(df.list_of_value.explode()).sum(level=0)
s.dot(s.T).div(s.sum(1))
```

Output:

```
          0         1         2         3
0  1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
1  0.666667  1.000000  0.666667  0.666667
2  1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
3  1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
```

---

**Update**: Here's a short explanation for the code. The main idea is to turn the given lists into one-hot-encoded:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  0
1  0  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  0
3  1  1  1  0
```

Once we have that, the size of intersection of the two rows, say, `0` and `1` is just their dot product, because a character belongs to both rows if and only if it is represented by `1` in both.

With that in mind, first use

```
df.list_of_value.explode()
```

to turn each cell into a series and concatenate all of those series. Output:

```
0    a
0    b
0    c
1    d
1    b
1    c
2    a
2    b
2    c
3    a
3    b
3    c
Name: list_of_value, dtype: object
```

Now, we use `pd.get_dummies` on that series to turn it to a one-hot-encoded dataframe:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
0  0  1  0  0
0  0  0  1  0
1  0  0  0  1
1  0  1  0  0
1  0  0  1  0
2  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  1  0
3  1  0  0  0
3  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0
```

As you can see, each value has its own row. Since we want to combine those belong to the same original row to one row, we can just sum them by the original index. Thus

```
s = pd.get_dummies(df.list_of_value.explode()).sum(level=0)
```

gives the binary-encoded dataframe we want. The next line

```
s.dot(s.T).div(s.sum(1))
```

is just as your logic: `s.dot(s.T)` computes dot products by rows, then `.div(s.sum(1))` divides counts by rows.

Comment: 12k rows dataframe

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar with 12k rows, you would end up with `12k x 12k` dataframe. Should be fine if you have around a few hundred unique values.

Comment: Good answer. It'll work as long as each list only has unique elements, like a,b,c and not a,a,b

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar This should probably be the right answer

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar Thanks for accepting my solution. Please see update for an explanation and thought logic.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
range_of_ids = range(len(ids))

def score_calculation(s_id1,s_id2):
    s1 = set(list(df.loc[df['id'] == ids[s_id1]]['list_of_value'])[0])
    s2 = set(list(df.loc[df['id'] == ids[s_id2]]['list_of_value'])[0])
    # Resultant calculation s1&s2
    return round(len(s1&s2)/len(s1) , 2)


dic = {indexQFID:  [score_calculation(indexQFID,ind) for ind in range_of_ids] for indexQFID in range_of_ids}
dfSim = pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(dfSim)
```

**Output**

```
     0        1      2       3
0   1.00    0.67    1.00    1.00
1   0.67    1.00    0.67    0.67
2   1.00    0.67    1.00    1.00
3   1.00    0.67    1.00    1.00
```

You can also do it as following

```
dic = {indexQFID:  [round(len(set(s1)&set(s2))/len(s1) , 2) for s2 in df['list_of_value']] for indexQFID,s1 in zip(df['id'],df['list_of_value']) }
dfSim = pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(dfSim)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use nested list comprehension on the list of set `s_list`. Within list comprehension, use `intersection` operation to check overlapping and get length of each result. Finally, construct the dataframe and divide it by the length of each list in `df.list_of_value`

```
s_list =  df.list_of_value.map(set)
overlap = [[len(s1 & s) for s1 in s_list] for s in s_list]

df_final = pd.DataFrame(overlap) / df.list_of_value.str.len().to_numpy()[:,None]

Out[76]:
          0         1         2         3
0  1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
1  0.666667  1.000000  0.666667  0.666667
2  1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
3  1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
```

---

In case there are duplicate values in each list, you should use `collections.Counter` instead of `set`. I changed sample data id=0 to `['a','a','c']` and id=1 to `['d','b','a']`

```
sample df:
id     list_of_value
0      ['a','a','c'] #changed
1      ['d','b','a'] #changed
2      ['a','b','c']
3      ['a','b','c']

from collections import Counter

c_list =  df.list_of_value.map(Counter)
c_overlap = [[sum((c1 & c).values()) for c1 in c_list] for c in c_list]

df_final = pd.DataFrame(c_overlap) / df.list_of_value.str.len().to_numpy()[:,None]


 Out[208]:
          0         1         2         3
0  1.000000  0.333333  0.666667  0.666667
1  0.333333  1.000000  0.666667  0.666667
2  0.666667  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
3  0.666667  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

Since there are a lot of candidate solutions proposed, it seems like a good idea to do a timing analysis. I generated some random data with 12k rows as requested by the OP, keeping with the 3 elements per set but expanding the size of the alphabet available to populate the sets. This can be adjusted to match the actual data.

Let me know if you have a solution that you would like tested or updated.

**Setup**

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

def random_letters(n, n_letters=52):
    return random.sample(ALPHABET[:n_letters], n)

# Create 12k rows to test scaling.
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': i, 'list_of_value': random_letters(3)} for i in range(12000)])
```

**Current Winner**

```py
def method_quang(df): 
    s = pd.get_dummies(df.list_of_value.explode()).sum(level=0) 
    return s.dot(s.T).div(s.sum(1)) 

%time method_quang(df)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
# CPU times: user 10.5 s, sys: 828 ms, total: 11.3 s
# Wall time: 11.3 s
# ...
# [12000 rows x 12000 columns]
```

**Contenders**

```py
def method_mcskinner(df):
    explode_df = df.set_index('id').list_of_value.explode().reset_index() 
    explode_df = explode_df.rename(columns={'list_of_value': 'value'}) 
    denom_df = explode_df.groupby('id').size().reset_index(name='denom') 
    numer_df = explode_df.merge(explode_df, on='value', suffixes=['', '_y']) 
    numer_df = numer_df.groupby(['id', 'id_y']).size().reset_index(name='numer') 
    calc_df = numer_df.merge(denom_df, on='id') 
    calc_df['score'] = calc_df['numer'] / calc_df['denom'] 
    return calc_df.pivot('id', 'id_y', 'score').fillna(0) 

%time method_mcskinner(df)
# CPU times: user 29.2 s, sys: 9.66 s, total: 38.9 s
# Wall time: 29.6 s
# ...
# [12000 rows x 12000 columns]
```

```py
def method_rishab(df): 
    vals = [[len(set(val1) & set(val2)) / len(val1) for val2 in df['list_of_value']] for val1 in df['list_of_value']]
    return pd.DataFrame(columns=df['id'], data=vals)

%time method_rishab(df)                                                                                                                                                                                                              
# CPU times: user 2min 12s, sys: 4.64 s, total: 2min 17s
# Wall time: 2min 18s
# ...
# [12000 rows x 12000 columns]
```

```py
def method_fahad(df): 
    ids = list(df['id']) 
    range_of_ids = range(len(ids)) 

    def score_calculation(s_id1,s_id2): 
        s1 = set(list(df.loc[df['id'] == ids[s_id1]]['list_of_value'])[0]) 
        s2 = set(list(df.loc[df['id'] == ids[s_id2]]['list_of_value'])[0]) 
        # Resultant calculation s1&s2 
        return round(len(s1&s2)/len(s1) , 2) 

    dic = {indexQFID:  [score_calculation(indexQFID,ind) for ind in range_of_ids] for indexQFID in range_of_ids} 
    return pd.DataFrame(dic) 

# Stopped manually after running for more than 10 minutes.
```

**Original post with solution details**

It is possible to do this in `pandas` with a self-join.

As other answers have pointed out, the first step is to unpack the data into a longer form.

```py
explode_df = df.set_index('id').list_of_value.explode().reset_index()
explode_df = explode_df.rename(columns={'list_of_value': 'value'})
explode_df
#     id value
# 0    0     a
# 1    0     b
# 2    0     c
# 3    1     d
# 4    1     b
# ...
```

From this table it is possible to compute the per-ID counts.

```py
denom_df = explode_df.groupby('id').size().reset_index(name='denom')
denom_df
#    id  denom
# 0   0      3
# 1   1      3
# 2   2      3
# 3   3      3
```

And then comes the self-join, which happens on `value` column. This pairs IDs once for each intersecting value, so the paired IDs can be counted to get the intersection sizes.

```py
numer_df = explode_df.merge(explode_df, on='value', suffixes=['', '_y'])
numer_df = numer_df.groupby(['id', 'id_y']).size().reset_index(name='numer')
numer_df
#     id  id_y  numer
# 0    0     0      3
# 1    0     1      2
# 2    0     2      3
# 3    0     3      3
# 4    1     0      2
# 5    1     1      3
# ...
```

These two can then be merged, and a score computed.

```py
calc_df = numer_df.merge(denom_df, on='id')
calc_df['score'] = calc_df['numer'] / calc_df['denom']
calc_df
#     id  id_y  numer  denom     score
# 0    0     0      3      3  1.000000
# 1    0     1      2      3  0.666667
# 2    0     2      3      3  1.000000
# 3    0     3      3      3  1.000000
# 4    1     0      2      3  0.666667
# 5    1     1      3      3  1.000000
# ...
```

If you prefer the matrix form, that is possible with a `pivot`. This will be a much larger representation if the data is sparse.

```py
calc_df.pivot('id', 'id_y', 'score').fillna(0)
# id_y         0         1         2         3
# id                                          
# 0     1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
# 1     0.666667  1.000000  0.666667  0.666667
# 2     1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
# 3     1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can conver the list to a set and use the intersection function to check for overlap:

(only 1 apply function is used as you asked :-) )

```
(
    df.assign(s = df.list_of_value.apply(set))
    .pipe(lambda x: pd.DataFrame([[len(e&f)/len(e) for f in x.s] for e in x.s]))
)

    0           1           2           3
0   1.000000    0.666667    1.000000    1.000000
1   0.666667    1.000000    0.666667    0.666667
2   1.000000    0.666667    1.000000    1.000000
3   1.000000    0.666667    1.000000    1.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all combinations. Then we can check with [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) and [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

```
from itertools import product
l = len(df)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array(list(map(lambda arr: np.isin(*arr),
                                                product(df['list_of_value'],
                                                        repeat=2))))
                               .mean(axis=1).reshape(l,-1),
                      index = df['id'],
                      columns=df['id'])

id         0         1         2         3
id                                        
0   1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
1   0.666667  1.000000  0.666667  0.666667
2   1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
3   1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
```

**Time sample**

```
%%timeit
l = len(df)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array(list(map(lambda arr: np.isin(*arr),
                                                product(df['list_of_value'],
                                                        repeat=2))))
                               .mean(axis=1).reshape(l,-1),
                      index = df['id'],
                      columns=df['id'])
594 µs ± 5.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be fast ,  also consider the duplicate in the list

```
... import itertools
... from collections import Counter
... a=df.list_of_value.tolist()
... l=np.array([len(Counter(x[0]) & Counter(x[1]))for x in [*itertools.product(a,a)]]).reshape(len(df),-1)
... out=pd.DataFrame(l/df.list_of_value.str.len().values[:,None],index=df.id,columns=df.id)
... 
out
id         0         1         2         3
id                                        
0   1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
1   0.666667  1.000000  0.666667  0.666667
2   1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
3   1.000000  0.666667  1.000000  1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! We're looking for a Cartesian product here, which is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas) answer. This can be achived **without a for loop or a list comprehension**

Let's add a new repeated value to our data frame `df` so that it looks like this:

```py
df['key'] = np.repeat(1, df.shape[0])
df

  list_of_values  key
0      [a, b, c]    1
1      [d, b, c]    1
2      [a, b, c]    1
3      [a, b, c]    1
```

Next merge with itself

```py
merged = pd.merge(df, df, on='key')[['list_of_values_x', 'list_of_values_y']]
```

This is how the merged frame looks like:

```py
   list_of_values_x list_of_values_y
0         [a, b, c]        [a, b, c]
1         [a, b, c]        [d, b, c]
2         [a, b, c]        [a, b, c]
3         [a, b, c]        [a, b, c]
4         [d, b, c]        [a, b, c]
5         [d, b, c]        [d, b, c]
6         [d, b, c]        [a, b, c]
7         [d, b, c]        [a, b, c]
8         [a, b, c]        [a, b, c]
9         [a, b, c]        [d, b, c]
10        [a, b, c]        [a, b, c]
11        [a, b, c]        [a, b, c]
12        [a, b, c]        [a, b, c]
13        [a, b, c]        [d, b, c]
14        [a, b, c]        [a, b, c]
15        [a, b, c]        [a, b, c]
```

Then we apply desired function to each row using `axis=1`

```py
values = merged.apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x[0], x[1]).shape[0] / len(x[1]), axis=1)
```

Reshaping this to get values in desired format

```py
values.values.reshape(4, 4)
array([[1.        , 0.66666667, 1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.66666667, 1.        , 0.66666667, 0.66666667],
       [1.        , 0.66666667, 1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 0.66666667, 1.        , 1.        ]])
```

Hope this helps :)