# Create DataFrame from multiple lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists

```
list1=['a','b','c']

list2=[1,2]
```

I want my dataframe output to look like:

```
col1     col2
a        1
a        2
b        1
b        2
c        1
c        2
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cartesian product in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas)

Comment: See second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46744050/365102... hmmm I guess it's not really an *exact* duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools

list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [1,2]
df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(list1, list2), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    a     2
2    b     1
3    b     2
4    c     1
5    c     2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to explicitly `import itertools`, `pd.MultiIndex` has a [`from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) method that you might piggyback on:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [1, 2]
pd.DataFrame(pd.MultiIndex.from_product((list1, list2)).to_list(), columns=['col1', 'col2'])
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    a     2
2    b     1
3    b     2
4    c     1
5    c     2
```