# Eliminate Column Repetition in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frames where I am trying to find all possible combinations of itself and a fraction of itself. The following data frames is a much scaled down version of the one I am running. The first data frame (fruit1) is a fraction of the second data frame (fruit2).

```
FruitSubDF     FruitFullDF
apple           apple
cherry          cherry
banana          banana
                peach
                 plum
```

By running the following code

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(fruitDF.iloc[0:3,0], fruitDF.iloc[0:5,0])), columns=['fruit1', 'fruit2'])
```

the output is

```
    Fruit1 Fruit2
0    apple  banana
1    apple  apple
2    apple  cherry
3    apple  peach
4    apple  plum
5   cherry banana
6   cherry apple
7   cherry cherry
.
.
18   banana banana
19   banana peach
20   banana plum
```

My problem is I want to remove elements with the same two fruits regardless of which fruit is in which column as below. So I am considering (apple,cherry) and (cherry,apple) as the same but I am unsure of an efficient way instead of iterRows to weed out the unwanted data as most pandas functions I find will remove based on the order.

```
    Fruit1 Fruit2
 0   apple banana
 1   apple cherry
 2   apple apple
 3   apple peach
 4   apple plum
 5  cherry banana
 6  cherry cherry
 .
 .
 15  banana plum
```

Comment: I see that your output has 5 of each fruit in the first column, as expected. So we have apple in rows 0-4, cherry in rows 5-9, some gap and then banana in the last rows, I suppose. What's the output in between? I tried running something similar here but I got 15 rows right away. It still has duplicates, but this many rows got me confused.

Comment: sorry, that was a miscount on my part. you're correct as original should have 15 then the adjusted would be 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I created a piece of code to replicate your DataFrame. I took my code here :[stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas)

```
import pandas as pd


Fruit1=['apple', 'cherry', 'banana']
Fruit2=['banana', 'apple', 'cherry']



index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([Fruit1, Fruit2], names = ["Fruit1", "Fruit2"])

df = pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()
```

Then, you can use the lexicographial order to filter the dataframe.

```
df[df['Fruit1']<=df['Fruit2']]
```

I have the result you wanted to obtain.

EDIT : you edited your post but it seems to still do the job.

Comment: Can you tell us if this does work since your last update ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools to achieve it -

```
import itertools
fruits  = ['banana', 'cherry',  'apple']
pd.DataFrame((itertools.permutations(fruits, 2)), columns=['fruit1', 'fruit2'])
```

Comment: ah sorry. I reclarified my question above. so this method would not work.