# Remove the requirement to loop through numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy

**Overview**

The code below contains a numpy array `clusters` with values that are compared against each row of a pandas Dataframe using `np.where`.  The `SoFunc` function returns rows where all conditions are `True` and takes the `clusters` array as input.

**Question**

I can loop through this array to compare each array element against the respective `np.where` conditions.  How do I remove the requirement to loop but still get the same output?

I appreciate looping though numpy arrays is inefficient and want to improve this code.  The actual dataset will be much larger.

**Prepare the reproducible mock data**

```
def genMockDataFrame(days,startPrice,colName,startDate,seed=None): 

    periods = days*24
    np.random.seed(seed)
    steps = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.0018, size=periods)
    steps[0]=0
    P = startPrice+np.cumsum(steps)
    P = [round(i,4) for i in P]

    fxDF = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'ticker':np.repeat( [colName], periods ),
        'date':np.tile( pd.date_range(startDate, periods=periods, freq='H'), 1 ),
        'price':(P)})
    fxDF.index = pd.to_datetime(fxDF.date)
    fxDF = fxDF.price.resample('D').ohlc()
    fxDF.columns = [i.title() for i in fxDF.columns]
    return fxDF


def SoFunc(clust):
    #generate mock data
    df = genMockDataFrame(10,1.1904,'eurusd','19/3/2020',seed=157)
    df["Upper_Band"] = 1.1928
    df.loc["2020-03-27", "Upper_Band"] = 1.2118
    df.loc["2020-03-26", "Upper_Band"] = 1.2200
    df["Level"] = np.where((df["High"] >= clust)
                                      & (df["Low"] <= clust)
                                     & (df["High"] >= df["Upper_Band"] ),1,np.NaN
                                      )
    return df.dropna()
```

**Loop through the clusters array**

```
clusters = np.array([1.1929   , 1.2118 ])

l = []

for i in range(len(clusters)):
    l.append(SoFunc(clusters[i]))
    
pd.concat(l)
```

**Output**

```
              Open  High    Low    Close    Upper_Band  Level
date                        
2020-03-19  1.1904  1.1937  1.1832  1.1832  1.1928      1.0
2020-03-25  1.1939  1.1939  1.1864  1.1936  1.1928      1.0
2020-03-27  1.2118  1.2144  1.2039  1.2089  1.2118      1.0
```

Comment: I can not reproduce it, can you give minimal reproducible code?

Comment: You should be able to copy and paste and run this as is.  It's data generated with numpy and pandas.  What error are you getting? I'm away from my laptop but will check your errors when home.

Comment: SOrry you are correct, I mistook warnings for errors

Comment: Replace lines with `df.loc["2020-03-27", "Upper_Band"] = 1.2118`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited based on @tdy's comment below)

`pandas.merge` allows you to make `len(clusters)` copies of your dataframe and then pare it down to according to the conditions in your `SoFunc` function.

The cross merge creates a dataframe with a copy of `df` for each record in `clusters_df`. The overall result ought to be faster for large dataframes than the loop-based approach, provided you have enough memory to temporarily accommodate the merged dataframe (if not, the operation may spill over onto page / swap and slow down drastically).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def genMockDataFrame(days,startPrice,colName,startDate,seed=None): 
    ''' identical to the example provided '''

    periods = days*24
    np.random.seed(seed)
    steps = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.0018, size=periods)
    steps[0]=0
    P = startPrice+np.cumsum(steps)
    P = [round(i,4) for i in P]

    fxDF = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'ticker':np.repeat( [colName], periods ),
        'date':np.tile( pd.date_range(startDate, periods=periods, freq='H'), 1 ),
        'price':(P)})
    fxDF.index = pd.to_datetime(fxDF.date)
    fxDF = fxDF.price.resample('D').ohlc()
    fxDF.columns = [i.title() for i in fxDF.columns]
    return fxDF
    
# create the base dataframe according to the former SoFunc
df = genMockDataFrame(10,1.1904,'eurusd','19/3/2020',seed=157)
df["Upper_Band"] = 1.1928
df.loc["2020-03-27"]["Upper_Band"] = 1.2118
df.loc["2020-03-26"]["Upper_Band"] = 1.2200

# create a df out of the cluster array
clusters = np.array([1.1929   , 1.2118 ])
clusters_df = pd.DataFrame({"clust": clusters})

# perform the merge, then filter and finally clean up
result_df = (
    pd
    .merge(df.reset_index(), clusters_df, how="cross") # for each entry in cluster, make a copy of df
    .loc[lambda z: (z.Low <= z.clust) & (z.High >= z.clust) & (z.High >= z.Upper_Band), :] # filter the copies down
    .drop(columns=["clust"]) # not needed in result
    .assign(Level=1.0) # to match your result; not really needed
    .set_index("date") # bring back the old index
)

print(result_df)
```

I recommend inspecting just the result of `pd.merge(df.reset_index(), clusters_df, how="cross")` to see how it works.

Comment: +1, but can avoid creating/dropping the `temp` columns by ["cross" merging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13270110/13138364): `pd.merge(df.reset_index(), clusters_df, how="cross").loc[...`

Comment: Ah, it's great that they introduced the cross merge. Thanks for the heads up -- I've updated the answer accordingly.