# How would I create new rows in a dataframe based on conditions of the columns?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say I have a dataframe like so:

| ID | Color | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Blue | 1 |
| BBB | Red | 1 |
| BBB | Red | 2 |
| CCC | Green | 1 |
| DDD | Yellow | 2 |

I have a list of all possible Types. In this case, the list is just ["1", "2"]. I want to create new rows (or a new df) so that each ID has a row for every type. The color value would stay the same for each ID. So the result I would end up with would be:

| ID | Color | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Blue | 1 |
| AAA | Blue | 2 |
| BBB | Red | 1 |
| BBB | Red | 2 |
| CCC | Green | 1 |
| CCC | Green | 2 |
| DDD | Yellow | 1 |
| DDD | Yellow | 2 |

I put the rows in order for simplicity and readability, but they dont actually need to be in order. Is something like this possible?

Comment: The operation you are trying to perform is known as the "Cartesian product", and you can find an answer on how you would accomplish this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13270110/11659881).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column with array of possible values and then explode it.
eg:

```
types_array = [1,2]

df = df.withColumn("types", F.array([F.lit(x) for x in types_array]))
df = df.withColumn("new_type", F.explode("types"))
```