# How to cross join (cartesian product) two Series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

Consider the following two series.

Let `x` be:

```py
x
a   10
b   20
c   30
Name: x_value
```

And let `y` be:

```py
y
d   100
e   200
Name: y_value
```

Ideally, the result would have a MultiIndex along with the cartesian product of the series' cross values:

```py
      x_value y_value
x  y
a  d    10      100
   e    10      200
b  d    20      100
   e    20      200
c  d    30      100
   e    30      200
```

I have seen similar questions (e.g. [cartesian product in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269890/cartesian-product-in-pandas)) about **cross merge**, but I haven't found anything about Series so far (let alone a MultiIndex of initial indices approach).

The part that seems troublesome to me is how I'd get to work with Series, instead of DataFrames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) works on Series, but it doesn't keep the index.

```
df = pd.merge(x, y, how='cross')
df
```

```
   x_value  y_value
0       10      100
1       10      200
2       20      100
3       20      200
4       30      100
5       30      200
```

You can just make the MultiIndex yourself:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([x.index, y.index], names=['x', 'y'])
df
```

```
     x_value  y_value
x y                  
a d       10      100
  e       10      200
b d       20      100
  e       20      200
c d       30      100
  e       30      200
```

- Docs: [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)

Comment: This is straightforward. The only part that I cannot completely understand is how would the MultiIndex that we construct afterwards align correctly with the values. Is there some behind the scenes mechanism that I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: @ttsak I'm not really sure what you're asking. When you take a Cartesian product of the values and a Cartesian product of the indexes, they have to align; that's just how Cartesian products work.

Comment: My question might be rather thoughtless. My only concern was that some indices would be mistakenly aligned with values from other pairs. But, I guess that behind the scenes, both `MultiIndex.from_product` and `cross merge` respect the initial ordering of indices / values?

Comment: @ttsak Yes, ordering is respected

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use `reset_index` and `merge`, then `set_index` multiindex:

```
s1 = pd.Series([10,20,30], index=[*'abc'], name='x_values')
s2 = pd.Series([100, 200], index=[*'de'], name='y_values')

s1.reset_index().merge(s2.reset_index(), how='cross').set_index(['index_x', 'index_y'])
```

Output:

```
                 x_values  y_values
index_x index_y                    
a       d              10       100
        e              10       200
b       d              20       100
        e              20       200
c       d              30       100
        e              30       200
```

Comment: To round it out, you could add `.rename_axis(['x', 'y'])`. (from [here](/q/49505080/4518341))